# readr - Importing date column in CSV

Tags: r, readr

I need an advice as to how import data using `readr` by inputing my own date format
The way i am trying is:

```
read_csv("test", col_types = cols( column-name = col_date("02/03/2015", "%d/%m/%Y))
```

But its giving me error

> " Error in col_date("02/03/2015", "%d/%m/%Y"): unused
>   argument("%d/%m/%Y")

When i test a single input using `parse_date("02/03/2015", "%d/%m/%Y")` it gives me the desired results

I would really appreciate if someone will help me, got stuck on this for last couple of days.

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `read_csv(filename, col_types=cols(col_date("%d/%m/%Y"), col_double(), ...))`. See [Column Types vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/vignettes/column-types.html).

Comment: Yes that worked, the mistake i was making, i was giving two inputs: one from column and one inside col_date function. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 5):

Building on comments, it should be something like:

```
read_csv(filename, col_types=cols(column-name = col_date("%d/%m/%Y"))
```