# How to allow skimr::skim_with function to output stats for date variable?

Tags: r, data-wrangling, skimr

I have a date variable in my data frame, but skim(df) will output the date variable as character variable. How do I specify in the code that it needs to recognize the date, and output range of the date variable?

`df = data.frame(date = c( "2/3/2021","2/4/2022","2/5/2019"), x= c(1,4,5), y = c(1909,1902,19092))`

Also, is the only way to correct the variable types so skim() recognize the correct variable type is by as.factor(df$column) or as.numeric(df$column2) before applying the skim() or skim_with()?

Thank you.

Comment: The original column is character type, thus it picks as character class.  You may need `df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: There is an option with `get_skimmers` for other datatypes to be added as in [skimr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/skimr/vignettes/skimr.html), but i think transforming the column type before applying would be better

Comment: Is there a way to automate the conversion process so I don't have to write multiple lines of as.Date to every needed column in the data frames?

Comment: you may check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38135764/readr-importing-date-column-in-csv

Comment: You would want to use as.Data() or a lubridate function, basically before skimming if you can generate a vector of the names you can lapply() and not have a long list of as.Data().